# Flexbox height increases while centering image

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I have the following code example:

```css
html,
body {}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: rows;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: rows;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
}

.center {
  align-self: center;
}

.whitebox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background-color: #bf8040;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background-color: #4d2600;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="whitebox"><img class="center" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Chess_rdt60.png"></img>
  </div>
  <div class="box"> </div>
  <div class="box"> </div>
  <div class="whitebox"> </div>
</div>
```

So I want to place an image with width and height of 60px into the flexbox with width and height of 80px, which should be no problem. However, the flexbox heights increase and decrease for the different boxes although I placed `justify-content: center`.

Do you have any suggestions in order to keep the height constant?

Thanks in advance.

Btw: Black rook image is from: By en:User:Cburnett - File:Chess rdt45.svg, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=20363786

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're not setting any heights on the flex items, they are naturally adjusting to their content size. The rook on the first row takes up more space than the emptiness on the second row, so the first row is taller.

Add this to your code:

```
.whitebox { height: 50%; }
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 160px;
    width: 160px;
 }

.whitebox {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    background-color: #bf8040;
    height: 50%; /* new */
 }

.box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    background-color: #4d2600;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="whitebox"><img class="center" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Chess_rdt60.png">     </div>
    <div class="box"> </div>
    <div class="box"> </div>
    <div class="whitebox"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much! :)